# Display whole fields from group (file + ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I made the ACF plugin group with files to download. In group I have fields "File 1", "File 2"...etc.
I would like to display all attached files to page. It is possible to display all fields belong to group? I try with basic code, but in this case I have only 1 file.

How can I add iteration to this or display all fields?

```
<?php

$file = get_field('attachment_1');

if( $file ): 

    // vars
    $url = $file['url'];
    $title = $file['title'];
    $caption = $file['caption'];

    if( $caption ): ?>

        <div class="wp-caption">

    <?php endif; ?>

<ul>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">

        <span><?php echo $title; ?></span>

    </a>
       </li>
<ul>

    <?php if( $caption ): ?>

            <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo $caption; ?></p>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It depends on how you have set up the custom fields, for example, are your "File1", "File2" etc fields in a repeater or have to created a separate field foreach? Are there any other fields in the group? Let us know the structure of the custom field group so we can help :-)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have created group - "PDF". In this group I have separate fields "File 1", "File 2", "File 3", "File 4", "File 5". There is also a statement field with informational heading how to attach a file.
I would like to display all fields from this group.

Comment: Was the answer below useful or do you need more help?

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks for your engagement. I try to match the code. Now I see all on backend (great), but I have a little problem with display it on front. For ex. I added 3 files, but on front I see only one. I think code needs change in part <li>..</li> to display all. Could you help me? Current code https://jsfiddle.net/qtpjpfgn/

Comment: Your jsfiddle isn't working because it doesn't support PHP, but looking at the code the main issue is that you are getting the files inside the loop, but you display them after the loop ends so only the last one is being displayed. You need to put the display code inside the loop too, and that should work.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the caption - it makes no sense to have it outside the file list because each file has its own caption. I've updated my answer below to include the file display inside the loop as I suggested in my previous comment. However I don't know what you want to do with the caption so I've ignored it - you will know where you need it so you can add it in yourself.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thank you very much for your help. Everything works. You have right - I need learn more about this. Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all your fields are set up individually, it isn't just a matter of looping through an array of all your fields of the same type (i.e. just your file fields).

There are a few ways that might work for you:

**Option 1.** 
*If all the field names for your files follow the same naming pattern and are named sequentially*, you could loop using the name.

Example, assuming your fields are named attachment_1 up to attachment_5:

```
$statement = get_field('name_of_your_statement_field');  
//do whatever you need to with $statement

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    //use the number from the loop to find the file by name
    $file = get_field('attachment_'.$i);  
    if( $file ){
        // display file details as appropriate
    }
}
```

**Option 2.** 
If the file field names do not follow the same pattern, you could loop through an array of the field names.

Example:

```
$statement = get_field('name_of_your_statement_field');
//do whatever you need to with $statement

// Create an array with the field names of all your files
// N.B. This also lets you specify the order to process them
$file_fieldnames = array('file_1', 'file2', 'another_file'); 

foreach ($file_fieldnames as $fieldname) {
    $file = get_field($fieldname);
    if( $file ){
        // display file details as appropriate
    }
}
```

**Option 3.** If you want to loop through ALL fields on the post/page, you can save the fields into an array.

This might seem like the most generic approach at first, but it is complicated by the fact that you don't know what type each field is in order to know how to process and display them... you first have to work out what field type it is. You could do this by name (similar to above) or you could try to identify what each field by checking the field content.

Note, checking the field content is very risky, as there are other field types that can have similar featured (e.g. a file is not the only type that can have a url) so I wouldn't advise that strategy unless you are 100% sure you'll never change the field group or add another field group to the post/page.

Example:

```
$fields = get_fields();
foreach ($fields as $fieldname => $content) {
    if (is_string ($content)){
        // display the string
    }
    else if (is_array($content) && $content['url']) { 
        // then you could assume its a file and display as appropriate
   }
}
```

Note that none of this code is tested. However it should give you an idea of the logic behind each option so you can decide what works for you.

**UPDATE based on new code provided:**

See below based on the code in your JSFiddle. I've ignored the caption outside the file list because it makes no sense - every file can have its own caption.

```
<?php

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    //use the number from the loop to find the file by name
    $file = get_field('attachment_'.$i);  
    if( $file ){
        $url = $file['url'];
        $title = $file['title'];
        $caption = $file['caption'];
        // now display this file INSIDE the loop so that each one gets displayed:
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" target="_blank">
            <span><?php echo $title; ?></span>
            </a>
            <?php if( $caption ): ?>
                <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo $caption; ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }    // end if 
}    // end for loop
?>
<ul>
```

If you understand arrays, I'd suggest you add the file details into an array and then do a second loop to display the files... however I'm guessing you're not that proficient with basic coding constructs as you don't understand loops, so I've tried to keep it simple. I **strongly** recommend that you do some tutorials on programming basics if you are attempting to write code.